# Numerical operations on arrays while reading from CSV file

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I am trying to do a few numerical operations on a few arrays  while reading some values from CSV files.

I have the coordinates of a receiver which is fixed and I read coordinates of the heliostats from a CSV file which track the Sun.

The coordinates of the receiver:

```
# co-ordinates of Receiver
XT = 0  # X co-ordinate of Receiver
YT = 0   # Y co-ordinate of Receiver
ZT = 207.724  # Z co-ordinate of Receiver, this is the height of tower 
A = np.array(([XT],[YT],[ZT]))
print(A," are the co-ordinates of the target i.e. the receiver")
```

The coordinates of the ten heliostats:
This data I read from a CSV file with the follwoing data:

```
#X,Y,Z
#-1269.56,-1359.2,5.7
#1521.28,-68.0507,5.7
#-13.6163,1220.79,5.7
#-1388.76,547.708,5.7
#1551.75,-82.2342,5.7
#405.92,-1853.83,5.7
#1473.43,-881.703,5.7
#1291.73,478.988,5.7
#539.027,1095.43,5.7
#-1648.13,-73.7251,5.7
```

I read the coordinates of the CSV as follows:

```
import csv
# Reading data from csv file
with open('Heliostat Field Layout Large heliostat.csv') as csvfile:
readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
X = []
Y = []
Z = []
for row in readCSV:
    X_coordinates = row[0]
    Y_coordinates = row[1]
    Z_coordinates = row[2]
    X.append(X_coordinates)
    Y.append(Y_coordinates)
    Z.append(Z_coordinates)
Xcoordinate = [float(X[c]) for c in range(1,len(X))]
Ycoordinate=[float(Y[c]) for c in range(1,len(Y))]
Zcoordinate=[float(Z[c]) for c in range(1,len(Z))]
```

Now, when I try to print the co-ordinates of the ten heliostats, I get three big arrays with all Xcoordinate,  Ycoordinate and  Zcoordinate grouped into one instead of ten different outputs.

```
 [[[-1269.56    1521.28     -13.6163 -1388.76    1551.75     405.92    1473.43
1291.73     539.027  -1648.13  ]]

 [[-1359.2      -68.0507  1220.79     547.708    -82.2342 -1853.83
-881.703    478.988   1095.43     -73.7251]]

 [[    5.7        5.7        5.7        5.7        5.7        5.7        5.7
   5.7        5.7        5.7   ]]]  are the co-ordinates of the heliostats
```

I used:

```
B = np.array(([Xcoordinate],[Ycoordinate],[Zcoordinate]))
print(B," are the co-ordinates of the heliostats")
```

What is the mistake?

Further, I would like to have an array where I wuold like B - A
for which I use:

```
#T1 = matrix(A)- matrix(B)
#print(T1," is the target vector for heliostat 1, T1")
```

How should i do a numerical operation on Arrays A and B? I tried a matrix operation here. Is that wrong?

Comment: I can't help you with your problem, but I might be able to help you debug it. Just before the for-loop line, add `import code; code.interact(local=locals())`. This should put you in the interactive console and let you see what all your variables look like. You might find that `csv.reader()` isn't doing what you think it's doing, or maybe you'll find that iterating over `readCSV` doesn't actually return the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your code is correct**

The following output is the way numpy arrays are displayed.

> [[-1359.2      -68.0507  1220.79     547.708    -82.2342 -1853.83
>   -881.703    478.988   1095.43     -73.7251]]

Despite the illusion that the values are stuck together, they are perfectly distinct in the array. You can access to a single value with

```
print(B[1, 0, 0])    # print Y[0]
```

The substraction of arrays A and B you want to perform will work

```
T1 = np.matrix(A)- np.matrix(B)
print(T1," is the target vector for heliostat 1, T1")
```

---

**May I make two suggestions ?**

- You can read a numpy array written as a matrix in a text file (it's the case here) with the function loadtxt of numpy :

  ```
  your_file = 'Heliostat Field Layout Large heliostat.csv'
  B = np.loadtxt(your_file, delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
  ```

  The result will be a (3, 10) numpy array.
- You can perform broadcasing operations directly on numpy arrays (so you don't need to convert it in matrix). You just need to be careful with the dimensions.

  In your original script you just need to write :

  ```
  T1 = A - B
  ```

  If you get array B with loadtxt as suggested, you will get a (10, 3) array, while A is a (3, 1) array. The array B must first be reshaped in a (3, 10) array :

  ```
  B = B.reshape((3, 10))
  T1 = A - B
  ```

---

**EDIT :** compute the norm of each 3D vector of T1

```
norm_T1 = np.sqrt( np.sum( np.array(T1)**2, axis=0 ) )
```

Note that in your code T1 is a matrix, so T1**2 is a matrix product. In order to compute sqrt( v[0]**2 + v[1]**2 + v[2]**2 ) for each vector v of T1, I first convert it to a numpy array.

Comment: Thank you very much!  The first option you suggested works perfectly!

Comment: Just an additional question -  If i want find the magitude of each of the new vector T1, when i write: 'modulusTVH1 = np.sqrt((T1)**2).sum()
print(modulusTVH1, "is the magnitude of this vector [t1], modulusTVH1")', I get just one output instead of ten different values. How can I write it so i get ten different values?

Comment: Hi, I just edited my answer to add the computation of the magnitudes. Sorry for being late.